# Need help understanding currying using groovy closures?

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, currying

I am trying to understand how currying works in functional programming. I have gone through [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and a couple of questions about the same on SO.

[Need help understanding lambda (currying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623956/need-help-understanding-lambda-currying)

[What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

I understand that currying is all about splitting a function that takes n arguments into n  or less functions with one argument each. I theoretically comprehend it but I am not able to connect the dots while coding for the same. Perhaps it is my lack of knowledge in functional programming  languages or C# (as many answers in the above questions deal with).

Anyway, I understand groovy & java. So I tried to get an outline for the standard `add(a,b)` function in groovy but I couldn't finish it.

```
def closure = { arg ->
   // ??
}

def add(anotherClosure , a){
    return closure // ??
}
```

Can someone help me understand currying using groovy closures?

Comment: I talk about Functional Programming with Groovy in a conference. You can see the [slides about currying with Groovy](http://www.slideshare.net/arturoherrero/functional-programming-with-groovy/32)

Comment: Went through all the slides. A very nice piece of information. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can roll your own currying functionality by writing a closure that takes another closure and a curried parameter to set, and returns a closure that uses this value.

```
// Our closure that takes 2 parameters and returns a String
def greet = { greeting, person -> "$greeting $person" }

// This takes a closure and a default parameter
// And returns another closure that only requires the
// missing parameter
def currier = { fn, param ->
  { person -> fn( param, person ) }
}

// We can then call our currying closure
def hi = currier( greet, 'Hi' )

// And test it out
hi( 'Vamsi' )
```

But you're better sticking with the inbuilt Groovy `curry` method [as shown by jalopaba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10511885/6509). (there is also [rcurry](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#rcurry%28java.lang.Object...%29) and [ncurry](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#ncurry%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29) which curry from the right, and at a given position respectively)

It should be said, that the Groovy curry method is a misnomer as it is more a case of [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) as you do not need to get down to a closure requiring only a single parameter, ie:

```
def addAndTimes = { a, b, c -> ( a + b ) * c }

println addAndTimes( 1, 2, 3 ) // 9

def partial = addAndTimes.curry( 1 )

println partial( 2, 3 ) // 9
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set a fixed value for one or more arguments to a closure instance using the `curry()` method:

```
def add = { a, b -> a + b }
def addFive = add.curry(5)
addFive(3) // 5 + 3 = 8
```

Another example:

```
def greeter = { greeting, name -> println "${greeting}, ${name}!" }
def sayHello = greeter.curry("Hello")
sayHello("Vamsi") // Hello, Vamsi!
def sayHi = greeter.curry("Hi")
sayHi("Vamsi") // Hi, Vamsi!
```